# Python add character to string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to open a user's text file and replace a string in Python. I have the replacement working, but to open a file I understand that I need to add another backslash after each one in the file path. I am not sure how to do that. I looked at other stack overflow questions, but they were mostly about adding to the beginning or end of the string. Please help! Here's the code so far:

```
yourfile = input()

with open ("C:\\Users\\Rajrishi\\Documents\\MyJava\\text.txt") as myfile:
    data = myfile.readlines()
    strdata = "".join(data)
    strdata = strdata.replace("a string","a replacement")
    print(strdata)
```

Comment: Be aware that `"C:\\text"` means "a 7-character string, whose characters are a `C` followed by a colon, followed by a backslash, followed by `text`. Whereas `"C:\text"` means "a 6-character string, whose characters are a `C` followed by a colon, followed by a tab character, followed by `ext`. So there's no question of "adding another backslash to the string" -- the string only needs one backslash for each separator, and the issue is how to get a string that contains a backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find it easier to pass a raw string by prefixing with `r`
like so:

```
with open (r"C:\Users\Rajrishi\Documents\MyJava\text.txt") as myfile:
```

This will mean that you don't need to escape slashes

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use forward slashes:

```
with open("C:/Users/Rajrishi/Documents/MyJava/text.txt") as myfile:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code and your file in the same folder, you can do this :

```
with open (r"text.txt") as myfile:
    ...
```

Just write name of the file.